# One select statement with multiple Group BY on the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I have 'TABLE_A' like this:

```
TVA  Amount   InvoiceID
----------------------
22  | 10.00 | inv-12
22  |-14.00 | inv-13
25  | 24.00 | inv-14
25  |-36.00 | inv-15
25  |-25.00 | inv-16
25  | 18.50 | inv-17
24  |-16.50 | inv-18
24  | 10.00 | inv-19
```

The goal is to make a groupBy TABLE_A.TVA value and by SUM(TABLE_A.Amount) > 0 and SUM(TABLE_A.Amount) <0, to get finally the sum of all positive Amounts grouped by TVA value, and the sum of all negative amounts grouped by their TVA value also

my Query is like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.TVA, TABLE_A.InvoiceID,
       SUM(TABLE_A.Amount) AS [PositiveTotalAMount],
       SUM(TABLE_A.Amount) AS [NegativeTotalAMount]  

 FROM TABLE_A
 GROUP BY TABLE_A.TVA
 HAVING SUM(TABLE_A.TVA) > 0
```

MY question is how to add the second grouping by on negative values, because  here i group only on SUM() > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_A.TVA, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN TABLE_A.Amount > 0 THEN TABLE_A.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [PositiveTotalAMount],
  SUM(CASE WHEN TABLE_A.Amount < 0 THEN TABLE_A.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [NegativeTotalAMount]  
 FROM TABLE_A
 GROUP BY TABLE_A.TVA
```

If you want to include the column `TABLE_A.InvoiceID` in the grouping then:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_A.TVA, 
  TABLE_A.InvoiceID, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN TABLE_A.Amount > 0 THEN TABLE_A.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [PositiveTotalAMount],
  SUM(CASE WHEN TABLE_A.Amount < 0 THEN TABLE_A.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [NegativeTotalAMount]  
 FROM TABLE_A
 GROUP BY TABLE_A.TVA, TABLE_A.InvoiceID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) expression:

```
SELECT
    A.TVA,
    A.InvoiceID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.Amount > 0 THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [PositiveTotalAMount],
    SUM(CASE WHEN A.Amount < 0 THEN A.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [NegativeTotalAMount]
FROM
    TABLE_A A
GROUP BY
    A.TVA,
    A.InvoiceID
```

Also, you must include all columns from the select list that are not aggregated to the GROUP BY list. `InvoiceID` was missing.

I also use the alias `A` for `TABLE_A` to increase readability.

Comment: The case expression returns either the positive or negative amount in `THEN` and otherwise `0` in `ELSE`, in which case it just sums 0. I.e., the SUM function is executed for every record either summing the amount or summing 0.